# Problem in Grandfather paradox

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, causality, time-travel

I am very confused about a paradox and a recent research on Quantum particles. I have  read an [article](http://www.physics4all.com/australian-physicists-stimulated-wormhole-expreimentaly-for-quantum-particles/) which states that time travel is possible for quantum particles. If it is possible then why does it violate the Grandfather paradox?

As far as I know that  f we can go to the past we can not change our past. They why a photon interacts with a past versions of photons?

Comment: For reference: [the original paper](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2014/140619/ncomms5145/full/ncomms5145.html)

Comment: The experiment didn't actually ***perform*** time travel, it ***simulated*** time travel, which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: I am not sure, could it just be an experiment like Double-Slit experiment in which it too showed that when observed they SEEMED to go back in time and choose an slit to go through and to behave like a particle?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): The author's "time machine" appears to be the standard Deutsch model in 0+1 spacetime dimensions, i.e. it has no spatial dimensions and only a (discretized) cyclic time. So general relativity plays almost no role here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First important thing to note is, as [Peter Shor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121678/problem-in-grandfather-paradox#comment246775_121678) points out, that this is just a simulation. There is a model that describes, how time travel could work on the quantum mechanical level and this is just a way to study it. This result does not mean that time travel **is** possible.

Time travel theorists, nevertheless, are well aware of all sorts of paradoxes that can appear. The way to go usually is to formulate a theory in such a way that it is **consistent.** Simply put, the laws of nature should prevent you from killing your own grandfather because it leads to a paradox.

This is not the only kind of paradox that can appear, though. Apart from these so called **dynamical paradoxes,** there are also **information paradoxes** (you read a proof of a theorem in a book, go to the past and write a book; where did the proof come from?) and other quantum paradoxes (distinguishability of non-orthogonal states, perfect cloning and so on). There are several theories that try to tackle these problems. There is a nice paper on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4933) that deals with some of the problems that arise with time travel. In addition to discussing several theories and their strengths and weaknesses, the author also gives a very nice introduction into the problem of paradoxes. This could help you if you want to understand this problem better.

Comment: I don't think your distinction between dynamical and information paradoxes is a good one.  Much better is to think of the well-posedness of dynamical systems: given equations of motion, the solution ought to *exist* and be *unique*. The grandfather paradox is just a colorful illustration of the failure of existence, and the unexplained book is just an illustration of the failure of uniqueness. (I believe the subjective value of the proof is a red herring.)